# How to remove basic authentication in angularness?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Hi am using basic authentication for webservie integration.

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + Base64.encode(Username + ':' + password);
        $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http:url.com'}).
            success(function(data) {
                if(data=='' || data==null || data=='undefined'){
                    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                        title: 'Info!',
                        template: 'Invalid Password, or no user found with this Email Address'
                    });
                    alertPopup.then(function(res) {
                        console.log('Invalid Password, or no user found with this Email Address ');
                    });

                }
```

This code is working fine for me .but my problem is if one user is logedin using username and password.then logged out after that another user try to logged in with different username and password will get the previous user loged in. how to clear the header authentication data?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably redefine the header with

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + Base64.encode(newUsername + ':' + newPassword)
```

Comment: HI i refined the header still it showing the same user

Comment: You can fetch in the $httProvider, to check if the header Authorization is defined there, It could be also redifined in an interceptor,

Comment: You can also try a grep -RC2 Authorization . at the root of your project to check where it is used, and see where it is redefined

Comment: Hi sorry for disturbing you,i am new in angularjs, How can u redefine httpprovider?

Comment: You can define a config block in your app in your app, for instance app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider){ $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Autentification']='etc ...}), but i suggest you to check in your code where it is redefined, searching the keyWord Authentication ... the other comment is write, you should define a method to log and a method to unlog, ,where you redefine your Header

Comment: I tried this also but not working , i contact with my back end programmer he told that "the user information is cached" in back end.is it possible to manage logout by deleting header auth from here?

Comment: If the data is cached in backEnd, you have to find the place where the authentication Header is redefined, The data is probably send to the response header, but you have to check where this response header is read, and where is the Authentication Header is redefined, Did you try to search the occurence of Authentication in Your code ?

Answer (score 0):

## It seems that,

You have **not replaced the `Authorization` header** when

1. the user logged out
2. logged in as a different user

**Login** - call this every time a user logs in

```
function setCredentials(username, password) {
    $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + Base64.encode(username + ':' + password); 
};
```

**Logout** - call this when a user logs out

```
function clearCredentials() {
    $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic ';
};
```

The above snippets simplified from this tutorial -  **[AngularJS Basic HTTP Authentication Example](http://www.jasonwatmore.com/post/2014/05/26/AngularJS-Basic-HTTP-Authentication-Example.aspx)**. i recommend reading it

---

## In addition,

Please note that using basic http authentication is **insecure** because the password passed on each request **with no encryption**!

As an alternative, you can change basic http authentication to a server side authentication using sessions (comment the server your'e using and i'll link you to example)

**If you still decides to keep the basic http authentication, at least use `HTTPS` !**

Answer (score 0):

I've found this solution working:

When initiating a logout, first try making a bad request with a fake user to throw away the currently cached credentials.

I have this function doing the requests (it's using jquery's `$.ajax` with disabled asynch calls):

```
function authenticateUser(username, hash) {
    var result = false;
    var encoded = btoa(username + ':' + hash);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function (request) {
            request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Basic ' + encoded);
        },
        url: "user/current",
        statusCode: {
            401: function () {
                result = false;
            },
            200: function (response) {
                result = response;
            }
        },
        async: false
    });

    return result;
}
```

So when I try to log a user out, this happens:

```
//This will send a request with a non-existant user.
//The purpose is to overwrite the cached data with something else
accountServices.authenticateUser('logout','logout');

//Since setting headers.common.Authorization = '' will still send some
//kind of auth data, I've redefined the headers.common object to get
//rid of the Authorization property
$http.defaults.headers.common = {Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"};
```